# Gain of a Modified Common Gate Amplifier

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog, small-signal

I want to know how the gain of the amplifier shown below can be calculated.

[image]

The gain turns out to be as shown, but why? I know that the gain of a common gate is gmRD, but is the circuit shown here a common gate?! Notice that the input is connected to the source directly.

[image]

Comment: yes, common gate and draw small signal model to calculate the gain if that is easier for you

Comment: Does not seem correct to me...If the input is a voltage source the gain has to be what you say gmRD but if the input is current source \$v_o/i_x\$ will be \$g_mR_{p1}R_{p2}/(1+g_mR_{p1})\$